# Multiple class attributes in HTML

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

What happens when an element has multiple `class` attributes?

```
<div id="test" class="one two three" class="four">
```

I'm trying to add a class to the output of `post_class();` in a WordPress plugin, but the function itself is creating the entire part `class="one two three"`

Is it equivalent to `class="one two three four"`?
Or does the first or second win?
Or is it undefined behaviour, in which case what do the major browsers do?

If you know the correct way of adding a class to this snippet (WordPress plugin), then that would also be appreciated!

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> What happens when an element has multiple class attributes?

When an attribute is declared multiple times for a single element (which is invalid HTML, by the way), behavior-wise the first value will override all subsequent values for the same attribute. So in this case, your element will only have the classes `one two three`.

This behavior is explained in [the HTML5 spec, 8.2.4.35 Attribute name state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-name-state), "... if there is already an attribute on the [element] with the exact same name, then this is a parse error and the new attribute must be removed..."

> If you know the correct way of adding a class to this snippet (WordPress plugin), then that would also be appreciated!

Typically, if you need to add custom classes dynamically to your WordPress posts, you hook onto the `post_class` filter and manipulate the `$classes` array as necessary. Here's what it roughly looks like in my themes:

```
function nv_post_class( $classes ) {
    // Most recent post on the front page
    global $count;
    if ( is_home() && 1 == $count )
        $classes[] = 'latest-post';

    return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'post_class', 'nv_post_class' );
```

If you only need to add one or more static classes, pass them as a space-delimited string directly to `post_class()`:

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'myclass1 myclass2' ); ?>>
```

More on this in the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class).

Answer (score 12):

Then the document will be invalid and the browser will attempt to perform error recovery.

From the [HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/parsing.html):

> If the attribute's name is already in attribute list, then return to the step labeled attributes.

So, if an HTML 5 parser is being used, the first attribute should apply.

Comment: At least in webkit and Firefox, this is correct, first classes are honored, subsequent are dropped. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sBp5Z/)