# Multiple CSS classes for same element using different class attributes

Tags: html, css

I need to specify multiple class attribute for HTML elements. When I tried with the following snippet, it applies only the `class a` but not `class b`.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
      .a
      {
         color:Red;
      }
      .b
      {
         background-color: Green;
      }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body class="a" class="b"> Hello World </body>
</html>
```

When I specify `class="a b"` works like a charm. But the problem is one of the class definition is derived from other sources like server side code. The actual code looks like:

```
<body $attributes class="b">
```

When the $attributes yields into a class attribute, class "b" is ignored.

Comment: I am afraid you need to _fix_ the server side code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple class attributes in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512330/multiple-class-attributes-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find a way to append your custom to class to the server-side variables. I assume the $attributes would contain many attributes beyond the `class` so you'll need to use a replace/regex style method.

If using php, maybe try:

```
$attributes = str_replace('class="', 'class="b ', $attributes)
```