# Issues making slide show. display none?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a slide show using jQuery but I can't get an element to show up once it is hidden. Here is my code:

```
<section id="content">
    <div id="jumbotron">
        <div class="slide" class="first-slide">
            <img src="IMG/Jellyfish.jpg" class="large">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="IMG/Koala.jpg" class="large">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="IMG/Penguins.jpg" class="large">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.slide{
    display:none; 
}
div.first-slide{
    display:block;
}
```

Why is it that the first image is not showing up ? I thought the display: block would override dispay: hidden.

Could someone please answer this question?
Thanks!

Comment: If the answer helped you, as you state in the comment, you should upvote it. If it solved your problem, you should accept it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple class attributes in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512330/multiple-class-attributes-in-html)

Comment: Yeah I tried, I don't have enough rep yet

Comment: You can always accept an answer to your question, there is no rep requirement associated. Also if you accept an answer, you get +2 rep, IIRC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have used the `class` attribute twice. You need to put the css classes in one `class` attribute.

So

```
    <div class="slide" class="first-slide">
        <img src="IMG/Jellyfish.jpg" class="large">
    </div>
```

Would become

```
    <div class="slide first-slide" >
        <img src="IMG/Jellyfish.jpg" class="large">
    </div>
```

Alternatively if you always show the first image then do not put a class on the `div` at all.

```
    <div>
        <img src="IMG/Jellyfish.jpg" class="large">
    </div>
```