# Dropdown onchange show or hide a div is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple dropdown and with chnage to this another div will be hidden or shown. If school is selected then the school names dropdown will be shown and again if private is selected then school names will be hidden.

html for this:

```
<div class="item">
                        <label>
                            <span>Select Your Institute type</span>
                            <select class="required" name="institutiontype" class="institutiontype">
                                <option value="private">Private</option>
                                <option value="school">School</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                        <div class='tooltip help'>

                            <div class='content'>
                                <b></b>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item school hidden">
                        <label>
                            <span>Select Your Institute type</span>
                            <select class="required" name="dropdown">
                                <option value="">-- Your institute Name --</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                        <div class='tooltip help'>
                            <span>?</span>
                            <div class='content'>
                                <b></b>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".institutiontype").change(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="private"){
                    $(".school").addClass("hidden")
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="school"){
                    $(".school").removeClass("hidden")
                }
            });
       });
```

and css:

```
.hidden{
    display: none;

}
```

Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/k8pkmxys/
Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two class attributes for select tag.

> [What happens when there are multiple class attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512330/multiple-class-attributes-in-html)

Please modify it as below.

`<select class="required" name="institutiontype" class="institutiontype">` change to

`<select class="required institutiontype" name="institutiontype">`

Also use `$(this).val()` instead of `$(this).attr('value')`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".institutiontype").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "private") {
            $(".school").addClass("hidden")
        }
        if ($(this).val() == "school") {
            $(".school").removeClass("hidden")
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
    <label> <span>Select Your Institute type</span>

        <select class="institutiontype required" name="institutiontype">
            <option value="private">Private</option>
            <option value="school">School</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <div class='tooltip help'> <span>?</span>

        <div class='content'> <b></b>

            <p>Choose Your Education Level Status</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item school hidden">
    <label> <span>Select Your Institute type</span>

        <select class="required" name="dropdown">
            <option value="">-- Your institute Name --</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <div class='tooltip help'> <span>?</span>

        <div class='content'> <b></b>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps