# How can I make spacing for Outlook E-Mails?

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, spacing

I am working on an E-Mail-template and have some issues due to special needs coding for Outlook E-Mails.
In the following I will show an example of a picture with what I tried to make some spacing on top of it.
But several options didn't work out.

However I tried different options like:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>       
<img src="img/btn_rng-ans.png" width="180" class="img-btn" style="Margin-top: -20px;">
<![endif]-->
```

Or

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>       
<img src="img/btn_rng-ans.png" width="180" class="img-btn" style="margin-top: -20px;">
<![endif]-->
```

Or

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>       
<img src="img/btn_rng-ans.png" width="180" class="img-btn" style="padding-top: -20px;">
<![endif]-->
```

Or

```
<style>
.rebtn {padding-top: -20px;}
</style>

<!--[if gte mso 9]>       
<img src="img/btn_rng-ans.png" width="180" class="img-btn" class="rebtn">
<![endif]-->
```

Or

```
<style>
.rebtn {margin-top: -20px;}
</style>

<!--[if gte mso 9]>       
<img src="img/btn_rng-ans.png" width="180" class="img-btn" class="rebtn">
<![endif]-->
```

None of them worked.
I would be very grateful if you could help me with this issue.

Cheers, JD

-------------------EDIT-------------------

So here is some more detail for better understanding:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin-top:20px">
<tr>
<td align="right">
<a href="#rg">
         <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
            <img src="img/btn_rng-ans.png" class="img-btn">
          <!--<![endif]-->

        <!--[if gte mso 9]>

<img src="img/btn_rng-ans.png" width="180" class="img-btn">

          <![endif]-->    

</a>
</td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

And here the external CSS Code for the image:

```
.img-btn {width:200px; margin-top: -40px !important;}
```

It should look like that:

[image: default Mail App on iMac]

But on Outlook on Windows its like that:

[image]

Comment: try to use one class attribute only and put all the classes there.. it could make the difference since it's not valid html like that and maybe only the first one will be considered otherwise (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512330/multiple-class-attributes-in-html) despite you already tried with inline styling and didn't work as well.. just my 2 cents. One last thing.. the width attribute is something old style.. so add it as a css attribute instead

Comment: You said that you want to make spacing, but I see that you are using a negative value of -20 (instead of 20) that will decrease the top spacing

Comment: https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=margin as you can see, negative margin is not supported. You have to figure out another way to come up with your desired design.

Comment: : @amel its a bit complicated... there is much more code especially external css code and  I can't find where someone made that spacing so I tried to decrease the spacing in the internal style space with negative values but that's not the problem here; I tried it also with positive values.

Comment: @DiegoD Thx for ur comment. But the attribute `class="img-btn"` is from an external css style which doesn't relate to only that E-Mail. Its something like a master for multiple E-Mails. So if I change something there it will change everywhere where Html codes relates to that. So it's not an option to add code to that. The other E-Mails working well though (different E-Mail with the same class attribute used). I use "old style" so I don't get more "in trouble" (as I am already with outlook-sh*t) with different browsers, apps and E-Mail providers. U see?

Comment: I was wrong about the `width` attribute since it's actually supported (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-width). But talking about the class attribute of the img element, that's totally unrelated with any other element using that class or with the css itself. The attribute of an element doesn't come from anywhere else but where the html is defined. What I suggested was doing `<img class="img-btn rebtn" ...` because there's no other way to do it in html. Defining class twice won't be valid.

Comment: It won't solve your problem but for sure it will make a further step in the right direction

Comment: @DiegoD unfortunately it doesn't work :( . It think I know why. As I already said the `class="img-btn"` is from an _external css_ ... what's that? -> [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp). And `class="rebtn"` from the _internal style_. So as I think this is why they couldn't work together like that: `<img class="img-btn rebtn" ...>`

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to reduce spacing in a pre-existing space. Without visuals and the code for that, it's hard to give you a definitive answer. You talk about a picture but don't provide it? Would be helpful.

Comment: @TruthMatters Did you finally find a solution to that?

Comment: @amel unfortunately not yet. But thx for asking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made the following to fix it:

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin-top:20px">
<tr>
<td align="right">
<a href="#rg">
<img src="img/btn_rng-ans.png" class="img-btn">
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin-top:-20px">
<tr>
<td align="right">
<a href="#rg">
<img src="img/btn_rng-ans.png" width="180" class="img-btn">
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
```

Instead of:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin-top:20px">
<tr>
<td align="right">
<a href="#rg">
         <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
            <img src="img/btn_rng-ans.png" class="img-btn">
          <!--<![endif]-->

        <!--[if gte mso 9]>

<img src="img/btn_rng-ans.png" width="180" class="img-btn">

          <![endif]-->    

</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Outlook listens to spacing on block-level elements like `<p>` and `<td>`.

You can use a paragraph to create spacing in the following way, noting padding will be ignored:

```
<p style="margin:20px 0 0 0; line-height:0; font-size:0;">&nbsp;</p>
```

Note I'm zeroing the height of the text with line-height and font-size, so that that does not get in the way (would be added to the height of the margin otherwise).

You could also just use the table if you have it already in place:

```
<td style="padding:20px 0 0 0;">
```

Outlook doesn't regard margin in a td. You have to use padding. No need to put it in the table as well.

Negative margins are only used when you want to overlap items, and you need a hack for that. But it appears that's a completely different question. What you need to figure out is what is causing the space.

Space in summary can be caused by:

- Padding on td, table
- Margin on p
- Line-height and font-size, even on 'empty' table cells (e.g. `<td></td>`)
- And remember to zero the cellpadding and cellspacing on tables: `<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">` unless you are specifically using it

Outlook ignores spacing on:

- divs (except for inline-level styles such as font-size)
- spans (except for inline-level styles)
- attempts at changing elements to block (through `display:block`), and any padding/margins on that (e.g. trying to do a button on an `<a>` element)

Comment: Bro I got it :)